# How can I serve a particular classpath resource at a given address using embedded jetty?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm looking to expose a clientacesspolicy.xml file from an embedded jetty server.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
ContextHandler capHandler = new ContextHandler();
capHandler.setContextPath("/clientaccesspolicy.xml");
capHandler.setBaseResource(Resource.newClassPathResource("clientaccesspolicy.xml"));
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.addHandler(capHandler);
...
httpServer.setHandler(handlers);
```

But I get a 404 accessing http://localhost:9000/clientaccesspolicy.xml

How can I expose a classpath resource to a given URL programmatically in Jetty?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because a `ContextHandler` doesn't actually server up content.
A small adjustment will make it *sort of* work, but to do what you really want you'll need to write your own handler.

The "*sort of* works" version:

```
ContextHandler capHandler = new ContextHandler();
capHandler.setContextPath("/clientaccesspolicy.xml");
ResourceHandler resHandler = new ResourceHandler();
resHandler.setBaseResource(Resource.newClassPathResource("clientaccesspolicy.xml"));
capHandler.setHandler(resHandler);
```

**But**, that version treats `/clientaccesspolicy.xml` as a directory, so it redirects to `/clientaccesspolicy.xml/` and then displays the contents of the XML file.

What it looks like you want is a version of the `ResourceHandler` that has a lookup of *url* => *resource*.
Jetty doesn't ship with a handler that does that, but you should be able to create a subclass of `ResourceHandler` and then override `getResource`. In that case you won't need [or want] the ContextHandler, just check for calls to "/clientaccesspolicy.xml" and map it to the correct ClassPath Resource.

Comment: sounds perfect, will give it a go! Thanks

Comment: update - both suggestions worked, but only the second created a usable client access policy file

Answer (score 20):

Actually, you can just register **a class path** as a class path resource (surprisingly).

```
ResourceHandler resHandler = new ResourceHandler();
resHandler.setBaseResource(Resource.newClassPathResource("/"));
server.setHandler(resHandler);
```

Then you can access whatever files are in your class path. So if you have a file.xml it will be served from localhost:9000/file.xml.